# Windows Store App with c#: how to load data from a fily (async) into UI?

Tags: c#, user-interface, asynchronous, file-io, async-await

I'm developing a Windows 10 Universal App. There is a RichEditBox and a ListView. Each time the User click an ListView-item the App should save the actual Content of the RichEditBox into a rtf file and load data from another file to display it in the RichEditBox. 
What's confusing to me is how to deal with asyc methods in the context of UI Calls. So, what will be "nice" code to accomplish that task? 
Basically I have a click method, that first calls the save method and then calls the load method. But... Should that click method be async? Should the load / save be async (i guess, because typically IO operations need to be awaited).
First thing i tried was this:

```
    private void MasterListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // don't care that UI will not wait on completion
        saveRtfFile("name");
        loadRtfFile("name");
    }

    private async Task saveRtfFile(String filename)
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile isfStorageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        if (isfStorageFile != null)
        {
            // Prevent updates to the remote version of the file until we 
            //finish making changes and call 
            Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(isfStorageFile);

            // write to file
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream randAccStream = await isfStorageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

            MyRichEditBox.Document.SaveToStream(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, randAccStream);

            // finished changing -> other app can update the file.
            FileUpdateStatus status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(isfStorageFile);

            if (status != FileUpdateStatus.Complete)
            {
                Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog
                errorBox = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("File " + isfStorageFile.Name  + " couldn't be saved.");
                await errorBox.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task loadRtfFile(String filename)
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile rtfStorageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        if (rtfStorageFile != null)
        {
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream randAccStream = await rtfStorageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            // Load the file into the Document property of the RichEditBox.
            MyRichEditBox.Document.LoadFromStream(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, randAccStream);
        }

    }
```

I guess that my "solution" is complete crap, since it throws fore some reason errors.
What is the correct way of handling the asynchronous IO calls inside the click method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you should do "async all the way" - that is, when you call a method, you should (sooner or later) `await` the task it returns. When you follow this principle, your event handler becomes:

```
private async void MasterListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
  await saveRtfFileAsync("name");
  await loadRtfFileAsync("name");
}
```

This will finish saving the file before loading it. The original code was starting to save and then trying to load before waiting for the save to complete, which may have caused your error.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I'll keep that rule in mind.